# Modify deployment process on elasticbeanstalk ami

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-ami

I've grown tired of trying to get elastic beanstalk to run python 3.5. Instead, I want to create a custom ami which establishes a separate virtualenv for the application (with python 3.5) and knows enough to launch the application using that virtualenv.

The problem is that once I ssh into the ec2 instance in order to create my custom ami, I am left wondering where the scripts are which govern the elastic beanstalk deployment behavior.

For example, when deploying via travis to elastic beanstalk, EB knows enough to look in a specific folder for the file `application.py` and to execute the file using a specific virtualenv (or maybe even the *shudder* root python installation of the machine). It even knows to execute a `pip install -r requirements`. Can anyone point me to where the script(s) are which govern this behavior?

**UPDATE**

Please see [Elastic beanstalk require python 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41814642/elastic-beanstalk-require-python-3-5) for those referencing the `.ebextensions` option. So far, it has not proved able to handle this problem due to the interdependency between the EB image operating system and the python environment used to run the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the EB files can be found in `/opt/elasticbeanstalk` - `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks` is probably most relevant for what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ebextensions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html) to run scripts you want when starting your ami.